# How can I plot a differential equation in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy, differential-equations

I want to plot the solution of my differential equation but I got this:

> '*ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes
>   (360,) and (1,)*'

When I write `_plt.plot(t,final[:1])_` I got

> '*Equality object is not subscriptable*'

statement.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sympy.abc import * 
import sympy as sy

L= float(input('L:'))
R= float(input('R:'))

v=220*sy.sqrt(2)
i=sy.Function('i')

q=sy.dsolve(sy.Eq(sy.Derivative(i(t)*L,t)+i(t)*R,v*sy.sin(t)),i(t)).evalf()
constant=sy.solve(q.subs(i(t),0),dict=True)

t=np.linspace(0,360,360)
final=q.subs(constant[0]).evalf()

plt.plot(t,final)
plt.show()
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you share the errors you got?

Comment: You can not plot a symbolic expression. You have to evaluate it at the desired times. Also it is doubtful that the constant computation does what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious from the code that `t` has 360 elements

```
t=np.linspace(0,360,360)
```

The error complains that `final` has an initial dimension of 1, where as it should be 360 like `t`.  While it is possible the `final` has (1,) shape (1 element, containing another array or list), more likely it is (1, n).

When you get `shape` errors, you need to look at the shape of relevant arrays,

```
print(final.shape, final.dtype)
```

and decide from that the correct way of adjusting the shapes.

`plot` can handle a second argument that is (360,m), where `m` is the number of lines that it should plot.